# "The maximum VALUE/ VALUES of A and B is 5 and 7, respectively

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> the maximum **value** of A and B is 5 and 7, respectively.

or

> the maximum **values** of A and B are 5 and 7, respectively.

Which one is correct?
I mean A = 5, B = 7.

Answer (score 1):

There are two values- the maximum value of A, and the maximum value of B. When you talk about the two together, there are still two values:

> The maximum values of A and B

Because there are two values, you have to use **are**, so you get:

> The maximum values of A and B are 5 and 7, respectively

If you talk instead about the total, that will be just one number, so you use the singular:

> The total of A and B is 12.

Comment: thanks for your answer!